# GCM Parameters displayed along with the message

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to push GCM using C#. I am successful in sending the message to the phone. But just that the entire string along with the parameters appear on the phone, instead of the 'message' parameter alone. 
 
Ie: for my message string : "gcmAction=gcmActionFeedback,title=Please provide Feedback,message=Your feedback please" 
In the phone notification I am able to see "gcmAction=gcmActionFeedback,title=Please provide Feedback,message=Your feedback please" where as I should be seeing "Your feedback please" only. 
 
The title is also not getting displayed. Whereas when I sent the same GCM message through http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/ , everything seems to be working perfect.

Plz plz help. This is the code

```
 
public string SendNotification2(string deviceId, string message)
        {
            string GoogleAppID = "AIza.......xkQk";
            var SENDER_ID = "6666666666";
            var value = message;
            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));
```

```
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + 
        System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put all your fields into a simple message string. If the message is a string, android will display the string exactly as it is.

So instead of `...data.message=" + value +...`  split your value into the different fields you want (gcmAction, title, ...) and add them accordingly to the url

```
string msg = "foo", title="bar", gcmAction="bla";
string postdata = "....&data.message="+msg+"&data.title="+title+"&data.gcmAction="+gcmAction +"&..."
```

I don't know the exact names of the fields required and/or supported, you may have to look them up in the documentation.

Or as an alternative: You could create a JSON object with the respective payload and transmit this playload in the body as shown in [this blog](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1223)

Comment: Working Perfect. Thanks a lot!